# bind onclick event on cloned image element

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

In my view I have list of several thumb. images. 
On page load first image is cloned and loaded in corresponding div. After that every image onclick is copied with larger dimensions inside that corresponding div.

**Now I need to bind onclick action on that copied element to reproduce for simplicity alert hello.**

Here's the code I have so far

```
<div id="detailsRight">
   <div id="showImage">
      //here will be copied thumb image
   </div>
   <div id="thumbImages">
      @if (Model.Images == null)
      {
         <h1> no image </h1>    
      }
      @foreach (var image in Model.Images)
      {
         <img src="@image.Path" class="details" width="50" height="50" alt="" />                             
      }
      </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        cloneImages();
    });
function cloneImages() {
        var imageObject = $("img.details").first();
        var clonedObj = $(imageObject).clone();
        clonedObj.height("250px").width("300px");
        clonedObj.appendTo($("div#showImage"));

        $(".details").click(function (event) {
            //clone the clicked image
            var clone = $(this).clone();
            clone.height("250px").width("300px");
            //place it in the placeholder
            $('div#showImage').html(clone);
        });
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking for this?

```
$('div#showImage').on('click','img',function(){
    alert('Clicked!');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    cloneImages();

    $('#showImage').delegate('img', 'click', function () {
        alert('Hello');
    });
});
```